# PowerDNS: setup/configuration help needed

Tags: dns, internal, resolve

Hope some can give me some help.
I have several network storage devices (from QNAP) and a few other network device like printers and so.
I have successfully installed **PowerDNS** on one of the QNAP (TS-269 Pro) and want to test this DNS application and use it to RESOLVE my internal devices.

So i am looking for some guidance in how to configure PowerDNS, and have my Linux/Mac/Windows clients use this DNS, so that **external and internal request will be resolved**.

Thanx in advance. for any help/guidance!

Answer (score 1):

You will likely be wanting to install PowerDNS recursor, not PowerDNS Server. The Server is for authoritative Nameservers and does not 'resolve' any domain name for you but just what you configure it to serve. The Recursor on the other hand serves that purpose but can also serve some static zones and data from /etc/hosts when given the configuration flag export-etc-hosts=yes. Its configuration file usually resides in /etc/powerdns/recursor.conf but depending on your distribution that may vary.

For general documentation please have a look at http://doc.powerdns.com/html/index.html .

For the recursor it also pays to limit max-cache-entries to a resonable value because if not set it could happily consume all available memory depending on the amount and diversity of queries received.
A few years back 1000000 entries amounted to around 700MB of memory usage (RSS) on an amd64 cpu architecture. Something like 10000 may however be sufficient for single computer personal use.